# converting TimeDate() string to a DATE data type

Tags: datastage

I`m trying to convert a TimeDate function`s result in DataStage to a DATE data type but i could not reach any solution. 
let go deeper. i`m trying to read from a file which contains 3 columns : name, ID and ACC#. then update a database table. THIS TimeDate function is added in the transformer in order to note down the table update date.
How can i convert this TimeDate to a DATE datatype yyyy-mm-dd. please someone help me.

NOTE: the datadabe i`m using is oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions :

1 - In the transformer stage add a new column and set it to CurrentDate()

2 - In the database connexion stage put in your query current date.